# $T_P(M)$ vs. $T_P(\partial M)$

Tags: differential-geometry, orientation, manifolds-with-boundary

I tried to understand in what way an orientation on $M$ induces an orientation on $\partial M$.  Note that I am learning in the context of the extrinsic definition of manifolds, i.e. everything is assumed to be $\subset ℝ^n$.

I stumbled upon the following sentence:

> A basis $(w_1, {}_\cdots, w_{k-1})$ of $T_p(\partial M)$ is said to be *positively oriented* if $(v, w_1, {}_\cdots, w_{k-1})$ being a basis of $T_p(M)$ is positively oriented

Where $v$ is said to be “pointing outwards”, which has been defined beforehand.

However, I thought: “How are $T_p(M)$ and $T_p(\partial M)$ even different for $P\in \partial M$? doesn't $T_p(M)$ ‘collapse’ by one dimension when looking at the boundary? Let's look at the definitions.”

> **Definition** (Tangent space)
>
> Let $M\subset ℝ^n$ be a k-manifold, $p\in M$. $T_p(M) := \{ v\inℝ^n \vert\, ∃ε>0\:∃γ \in C^1((-ε,ε),\,M) : γ(0)=p\wedge γ^\prime(0)=v \}$

However, when $p\in \partial M$, for every such map $γ$ we find a chart $Φ: \mathcal T(ℝ^k_-)\ni T→M$ (choosing $ε$ s.t. $γ[(-ε,ε)]\subset W$) s.t. $Φ^{-1}\circ γ$ is a continuously differentiable curve in the half-space with $(Φ^{-1}\circ γ)\,(0) ∈\partial ℝ^k_-$. Thus, the first component of $v=(Φ^{-1}\circ γ)$ is zero and thus $\dim T_p(M) = k-1$.

What is wrong with my argumentation? Or are the definitions of the tangent space insufficient?

I will happily give more of the definitions we used if needed.

Comment: The definition of the tangent space you quote is for manifolds without boundary. You probably have a different one for manifolds with boundary.

Comment: I cannot find one. Immediately after defining $ℝ^k_-$, we define “submanifold with boundary” and prove “$M$ is orientable ⇒ $\partial M$ is orientable” and use $T_p(M)$ in a remark.

Does this mean the script is actually inconsistent/incomplete?